# EF6 Fluent Api - I need to set Default value in FluentApi in order to Map Child to be used instead of Parent

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, default-value, ef-fluent-api

Here's part of the setup. Names are simplified: 
I have following classes:

- MyClass
- MySubclass1 : MyClass
- MySubClass2 : MyClass

`MyClass` is part of another class (and table), which I will leave out.

I'm trying to do an **EF6 query** (using `context.Set<MyClass>.Where(...)`)

I want to return the subclasses instead of the parent class and I want to avoid using the `Discriminator`. The reason is: there is a property on MyClass that already defines whether it's `MySubclass1` or `MySubclass2`.
The property is called `KindId` and is an `FK` to a lookup table (`Kinds`).

The EF-part is being autogenerated as follows:

```
public partial class MyClassMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassMap ()
    {
        ToTable("MyClasses", "MySchema");
        //...etc (other implementations)

        HasRequired(c=> c.Kind)
            .WithMany(kind => kind.MyClasses)
            .HasForeignKey(c => new { c.KindId });

        Initialize();
    }

    partial void Initialize();
}
```

This means, I can only update Initialize().
I have done so as follows:

```
public partial class MyClassMap 
{
    partial void Initialize()
    {
        Map<MySubclass1>(c => c.Requires("KindId").HasValue(1));
        Map<MySubclass2>(c => c.Requires("KindId").HasValue(2));
    }
}
```

When I run the EF query, I'm getting following exception:

> error 3023: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines x:Column
>   MyClass.KindId has no default value and is not nullable. A column value
>   is required to store entity data.

I tried setting the default value on the DB, but I think it requires the Default to be set within EF. 
**Question is: how do I do this using the FluentApi?**

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting an error because it doesn't know what discriminator value to use for the base class.  So, I think you also need a map for the base class -- for example:

```
Map<MyClass>(c => c.Requires("KindId").HasValue(0));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's quite a good suggestion. Unfortunately, it changes the exception to following: 'The type MyClass has already been mapped to table 'MySchema.MyClasses'. Specify all mapping aspects of a table in a single Map call.' I do know that it is mapped, just not in the current map. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ah, yea, the `Map<MyClass>` also needs to include `c.ToTable("MyClasses", "MySchema")`...but if you can't modify the generated configuration....

Comment: You are correct, the .ToTable is unfortunately generated :(

Comment: @Recipe: what are you using for the code generation?

Comment: It's a domain modeling tool (custom written by framework guys) that translates (together with T4-templates) to c#